# Question on Continuity of Functions...

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

If a function f defined on R is such that |f| is continuous,then f is also continuous on R. Please comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint:  Consider $$ f(x) = \left \{ \begin{array}{cc} -1 & x < 0 \\ 1 & x \geq 0 \end{array} \right. $$